# MS Access 2016 Reference a field on a sub Report within a Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I had a form with a sub form. The form contained the following VBA conditional formatting and everything worked like a charm:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
x = Date + 183
y = Date + 91
z = Date + 30
On Error Resume Next
    Select Case Me.tblContractTotalOptionsIncluded
        Case Is = Me!subfrmContractCLIN.Form.tblContractCLINDescriptionID - 1
            Select Case Me!subfrmContractCLIN.Form.tblContractCLINExpirationDate
                Case Is < Date
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(70, 0, 0)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End Select
        Case Is > 5
        Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(70, 0, 0)
        Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
        Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case Else
            Select Case Me!subfrmContractCLIN.Form.tblContractCLINExpirationDate
                Case Is < Date
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Case Is < z
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 242, 0)
                Case Is < y
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 242, 0)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Case Is < x
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 242, 0)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                Case Else
                    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = False
                    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

My users complained that they wanted things to look more like a F$%@*$g excel spreadsheet. So being the accommodating guy that I am, amongst other aesthetic changes, I’ve changed the “subfrmContractCLIN” sub form to a report named “subrptContractCLIN” because the Can Grow properties on reports work better than they do on a continuous form. To make the report I copied the Record Source SQL from the sub form and used it for the sub report. All the fields I had on the sub form are included in the sub report.

The following is an excerpt of the above code with my changes. As you may have guessed the code below does not work.

```
Select Case Me.tblContractTotalOptionsIncluded
    Case Is = Me!subrptContractCLIN.Report.tblContractCLINDescriptionID - 1
        Select Case Me!subrptContractCLIN.Report.tblContractCLINExpirationDate
            Case Is < Date
                Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(70, 0, 0)
                Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
                Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End Select
    Case Is > 5
    Me.tblContractNumber.BackColor = RGB(70, 0, 0)
    Me.tblContractNumber.FontBold = True
    Me.tblContractNumber.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case Else
        Select Case Me!subrptContractCLIN.Report.tblContractCLINExpirationDate
```

Any assistance you can provide me so I can help my excel loving, metathesiophobic users sleep at night would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running this code in the `OnFormat` event of the report details section.

Comment: I'll give it a shot thanks

Comment: well i gave it a shot and i got nothing, I’m open to any other ideas.

Comment: I’m an idiot.  the code I posted originally did work. The problem was “tblContractCLINDescriptionID” in the first set of code should have changed to “tblContractCLINOptionID” in the second set of code. So sorry for wasting your time Andre.